# Why do frequency synthesizers often use N/N+1 prescalers?

Tags: pll, synthesizer

Frequency synthesizers, like [Analog's ADF411x](http://www.analog.com/static/imported-files/data_sheets/ADF4110_4111_4112_4113.pdf) often have prescalers in their PLL which divide by 16/17, 32/33 or 64/65? What's the 2^N+1 value used for?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A dual-modulus (fractional N) pre-scaler gives the PLL increased resolution, without compromising things like lock time and noise. See [this](http://focus.ti.com/lit/an/swra029/swra029.pdf) app note.

Comment: That's a pretty good read for the fractional N system. I didn't know that's how it worked. Thanks!

Comment: Note that the use of a dual-modulus prescaler does not, by itself, imply a fractional-N design.  N/N+1 dividers are also used in integer-N parts, like most of the ADF411x series.

Answer (score 2):

Another Excellent PLL reference is this one

http://www.national.com/analog/timing/pll_designbook